# oci.dll for database connectivity

Tags: c++, database, oracle, occi, oracle-client

I am using OCCI to connect to oracle database through an already implemented application.

This Application lets says "A" already connects to database 1. This implementation is complete Out of the box.
Now I am putting some specific code here to connect to database 2. For this custom code I am using Oracle instant client. So as part of this I need to deploy additional dlls (oci,oraocci.dll)

Now I see an conflict here with oci.dll. The initial application already has oci.dll if I replace this one with my new one. I see application crashing. And if plan to use same oci but just add oraocci. I see failure in connectivity.

Can somebody suggest some solution here?

P.S. Both database 1 and database 2 are at different versions.

Comment: Recompile the other application after changing the dll.

Comment: I dont have source code for that application, its an third party one...